# Search leaves space from the bottom

Tags: vim

When searching in Vim and the match isn't on the visible page then vim will scroll to the next match. The match will be placed on the last row (at the bottom). 
Is it possible to make the match appear a few rows from the bottom. So that I can se the next few rows?
Perhaps it is possible to set this as setting in the vimrc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need this

```
:set scrolloff=3
```

which always makes sure there are at least 3 lines below/above your cursor.